# What does a method "do" when it awaits an empty Task?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am outlining a class and to keep myself happy I have made a temporary return for a method

```
public override Task DoPostProcessing()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ;} );
}
```

If I were to call this method and `await` it, what "happens"? Is this `Task` optimized away at compile time or is it ran?

Comment: When the awaiter state machine is created, there is a short circuit path that asks if the function has already ran, if it has, it will just return. From my memory it is bad practise to return `Task`, should just use `async` `await`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is run. It will schedule a method on a thread pool that just returns immediately.

On a side note, [do not use `StartNew`; it is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). Use `Task.Run` to run code on a thread pool thread, or just use `Task.FromResult` to return an already-completed task. `Task.FromResult` should be your go-to choice for noop implementations.

Comment: I knew about `StartNew`, I still use it out of habit sometimes :(. Thanks for the answer, this makes sense!